# Problema con las rutas de React Router en producción

Tags: reactjs, rutas, react-router-dom, router

Mi problema surge cuando paso mi aplicación a producción, la url cambia pero no se renderiza el contenido, no es hasta que estando en esa ruta y recargo que se renderiza el contenido de dicha ruta.

Me di cuenta de este error al querer subir mi app con AWS Amplify. Aunque también lo comprobe al realizar un yarn build y probar la aplicación.

Si sirve, incluso al arrancar la aplicación se ve solo asi, es decir se renderiza toda la plantilla menos el contenido de la ruta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dejo mi codigo:

AppRouter.js

```
function AppRouter() {
  console.log('main')
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <ScrollToTop/>
      <Layout>
        <Routes>          
          <Route exact path="/home" element={<Home />} />
          <Route exact path="/about" element={<Us />} />
          <Route exact path="/service/:id" element={<Services />} />
          <Route exact path="/news" element={<News />} />
          <Route exact path="/contact" element={<Home />} />
          <Route exact path="/contact/sale" element={<Sale />} />
          <Route exact path="/contact/recruitment" element={<Recruitment />} />         
          <Route exact path="/*" element={<Navigate to="/home" />} />
        </Routes>
      </Layout>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

function ScrollToTop() {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [location]);


  return null;
}

export default AppRouter;
```

Layout.js (aqui cabe aclarar que para mis componentes uso lazy, excepto para Container)

```
function Layout({ children }) {
    console.log(children)
  const [servicesList, setServiceList] = useState([]);
  const [contactsList, setContactsList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("effect");
    const getData = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await getServices();
        const contacts = await getAllContacts();
        setServiceList(data.services);
        setContactsList(contacts.contacts);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error getting info");
      }
    };
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <CustomNavbar servicesList={servicesList} />
      <Container fluid className="m-0 p-0">
        {children}
      </Container>
      <ContactButton contactsList={contactsList} />
      <UpButton />
      <Footer contactsList={contactsList} servicesList={servicesList} />
    </>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```